# Yodlee searchSite returning component with multiple values

Tags: yodlee

The [Yodlee docs for siteSearch](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/searchSite) shows a componentList array with each entry looking like this:

```
{
    "valueIdentifier": "LOGIN",
    "valueMask": "LOGIN_FIELD",
    "fieldType": {
        "typeName": "TEXT"
    },
    "size": 20,
    "maxlength": 22,
    "name": "LOGIN",
    "displayName": "User ID",
    "isEditable": true,
    "isOptional": false,
    "isEscaped": false,
    "helpText": "101920",
    "isOptionalMFA": false,
    "isMFA": false
},
```

however, when the siteSearch is matches "baa", we get a response with a componentList array entry that seems to have multiple possible values, like this:

```
{
\"defaultValues\": [
  \"6331\",
  \"5700\",
  null,
  null
],
\"values\": [
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null
],
\"validValues\": [
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null
], ...
```

I can't find any documentation on this "multiple-value field", and it seems to be a rare case. Can anyone point me to any information on this type?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to check [this](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getLoginFormForContentService/Sample_JSON_Responses_for_Different_Login_Forms#Login_form_with_multiple_fixed_field_information).
Here look for Social Security Number example. It is a single field which has been divided into 3 section(i.e. input text box). Similarly you need to consume the Login form you are receiving and show it to the consumer of your application.
Whenever you'll find valueIdentifier is having an array i.e. more than 1 value then it is multiple fixed field type else it's a single field.

Here is the image how does it look like once you render the same.

[image]